# My Doughnut icing ends look weird Blender

Tags: modeling, sculpting

[image: Jagged doughnut ends]

Hi,

I'm following Blender Guru's doughnut videos. At one point, when I was making the icing I encountered an issue and changed some settings around. After a few days, I managed to fix the issue, but now this this is stuck here and I don't know how to get it back. Does anyone know what I enabled?

Thanks,

Comment: Love Blender Guru!

Comment: Yeah, me too :D

Comment: could you share your file with me so I can take a closer look?  you can use this link:https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Right Click, select Shade smooth

Comment: Ethan, where do I find the files? Sorry, I'm a complete beginner )L